# Bibtex alpha reference with multiple-component surnames

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using the `alpha` referencing style and want to compile a reference with two or more authors, in which the surname-component of at least one of the authors' full names has two or more parts. For instance when I try to compile the following reference

```
@misc{article1,
    author={Lastnameone Lastnametwo, Firstnameuno
           and Surnamedos, Firstnamedos},
    year={2021},
    ...
}
```

it outputs `[LLS21]`. However, I would prefer it to output `[LS21]`, i.e., to take into account only the first part of the two-part surname. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to clarify the typesetting problem. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you replace

```
Lastnameone Lastnametwo, Firstnameuno
```

with

```
Lastnameone\space{}Lastnametwo, Firstnameuno
```

in the `author` field. This method works because, early on during its processing, BibTeX "purifies" [yes, that's actual BibTeX terminology!] the contents of various fields by removing any embedded macros. Thus, the purification step removes `\space` and leaves behind

```
LastnameoneLastnametwo, Firstnameuno
```

This means that *during the label-forming stage*, BibTeX only sees "LastnameoneLastnametwo" -- and thus chooses `L` to form part of the name label, as long as the entry in question has two or more authors. BibTeX will write out

```
Firstnameuno Lastnameone Lastnametwo
```

to the .bbl file -- and that's what LaTeX will "see" and process during the typesetting phase.

Hopefully, not too many entries in your bibliography will need to be treated in this manner.

---

Here's a minimum working example and its associated output:

[image]

Without the suggested treatment of the surnames, the citation call-out labels would be `[BCST01]` and `[GPDN02]`, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{hbc-kst:01,
  author = "Bonham\space{}Carter, Helena and Scott\space{}Thomas, Kristin",
  year   = 3001, title = "Thoughts"}
@misc{agp-mdn:02,
  author = "Garcia\space{}Pascual, Antonio and Del\space{}Negro, Marco",
  year   = 3002, title = "Thoughts"}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{document}
\noindent \cite{hbc-kst:01} and \cite{agp-mdn:02} \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Addendum: To deal with two-part surnames that are joined with a hyphen ("dash") character rather than separated by a space token, just replace `\space{}` with `\discretionary{-}{}{-}`.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. Just tried this and it worked perfectly :)